# Foundation media query - hide-for-small-only

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

The .hide-for-small-only is max-width 0 - 39.9375em

But the .show-for-small-only is at 0em - 40em.

Shouldn't the .hide-for-small-only be 0 -40em since that is the number for .show-for-small-only? Why is there a max-width different between these two queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
  .hide-for-small-only {
    display: none !important; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 0em), screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .show-for-small-only {
    display: none !important; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times where expedient code and comprehensible code are slightly different things.

> *Foundation's @Media Queries*
>
> /* Small only */ @media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {}
>
> /* Medium and up */ @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {}
>
> /* Medium only */ @media screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width:
> 63.9375em) {}
>
> /* Large and up */ @media screen and (min-width: 64em) {}
>
> /* Large only */ @media screen and (min-width: 64em) and (max-width:
> 74.9375em) {}

So when width === 40em, we'd be expecting **medium**.

The reason that `.hide-for-small-only` is `max-width: 39.9375em`is that it is possible for `width` to exactly equal `39.9375em` and for the condition to be true (e.g. hide). So for all width values within the `small` range this element is **hidden** by `display: none`. This is pretty straightforward and easy to read.

Whereas if you want to **show** the element (`.show-for-small-only`) for 0 to 39.9375em only, then the first width where you'd want to **hide** the content would be one pixel over `small` === 40em (hence `min-width: 40em`). This is not a media query to say show between x and y, it is to say hide under x and over y.

The most confusing part is really because they are named as though one "hides" and the other "shows"... but actually they BOTH hide, but at different widths.

I assume the `max-width: 0em` is because the @media query is generated by a SASS mixin and that has to work for all the "only" classes, which would actually need a `max-width` to define the bottom width, but not so much for small.